# Finding an interior angle between two interior angles

Tags: angle

In the picture below; shows how it is illustrated:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIRfj.jpg

I am trying to find angle b; given angles a and c. The value for angle a is 32 degrees, and for c it is 77degrees. How much is angle b?

I tried subtracting a and c; which gave me 45 and yet I ain’t sure about that coz if you look at the figure, it doesn’t really look like a 45.

Comment: What is the small angle where you have the letter c?

Comment: What do you mean? I don’t understand. I am trying ti find the angle between a and c as seen in the illustration.

Comment: Your big angle c is made out of 3 smaller ones: a, b, an the angle on the right, where you have the letter c.

Comment: It is not given.

Comment: Then you cannot solve the problem. Check again. It might say that it is equal to a or b.